# Cycles render transparent glossy

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, glass

this is completed render transparent. I saved it as a png. but I open in photoshop it looks like this. After rendering it showed good but after save not good. who can help me how can I fix it
[image]

[image: this is in photoshop. transparent part view very bad.][!this is setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpLzu.png) ][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpLzu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save Alpha channel, it's not enough to set file format to PNG.

Also you need to enable RGBA Color mode, where A after RGB means Alpha.

[image]